# Conditional field jQuery library not working with Checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, conditional-statements

I am using a small jQuery library **jQuery-Visibly** 
A jQuery Plugin designed to easily Conditionally show elements based on values of other Form elements.

Project page and documentation: http://www.danielrivers.com/visibly
Project GitHub Page: https://github.com/DanielRivers/jQuery-Visibly/blob/master/js/jquery-visibly.js

**Some key features that put it above some other libraries:**

- **Multiple fields and values** can be set as a rule for revealing a hidden field instead of only a single field to field rule like other libraries do.  Example; To show field 3 I can require both field 1 and field 2 to have a certain value set in both at the same time in order for field 3 to become visibble.
- **RegEx matching** - require a text inputs text value to match the regex pattern in order for a conditional field reliant on it to be shown.

---

Below is my demo where I am trying to use checkboxes to reveal a hidden DIV.

In DIV ID `#test` I have a conditional rule set with `visibly="foo:checked;foo3:checked"`

This means field `#foo` and `#foo3` should both be checked in order to reveal `#test`

However it is not working.  It is possibble that  the library only supports select and input fields and not checkbox fields but looking at the library code (125 lines) https://github.com/DanielRivers/jQuery-Visibly/blob/master/js/jquery-visibly.js on line 60 mI saw `:checked` which made me think it is supported but I am not 100% certain of it?

Could someone look at this to see if checkboxes should work with what I am doing?

**DEMO:** https://jsfiddle.net/955us4ge/

**HTML**

```
<label for="foo">
  <input id="foo" name="foo" type="checkbox"> Foo
</label>

<label for="foo2">
  <input id="foo2" name="foo2" type="checkbox"> Foo2
</label>

<label for="foo3">
  <input id="foo3" name="foo3" type="checkbox"> Foo3
</label>

<div id="test" class="conditional" visibly="foo:checked;foo3:checked">
  this should be hidden until checkbox #foo and #foo3 are both checked
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#test').Visibly();
});
```

---

Answer (score 0):

The Visibly plugin seems to check the `value` attribute of the elements that you added to the rules and checks if the value meets the condition. So if you want it to work with `checkbox` elements you will need to change the `value` attribute on them.

Here is an example.

```js
$('#test').Visibly();

$("input").on("click", function() {
  if($(this).prop("checked")) {
    $(this).val("checked");
  } else {
    $(this).val("");
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/DanielRivers/jQuery-Visibly/master/js/jquery-visibly.js"></script>


<label for="foo">
  <input id="foo" name="foo" type="checkbox" value=""> Foo
</label>

<label for="foo2">
  <input id="foo2" name="foo2" type="checkbox" value=""> Foo2
</label>

<label for="foo3">
  <input id="foo3" name="foo3" type="checkbox" value=""> Foo3
</label>



<div id="test" class="conditional" visibly="foo:checked;foo3:checked">
  This should be hidden until checkbox #foo and #foo3 are both checked
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you'd like to do this with plain jQuery:

https://jsfiddle.net/rjmu8dus/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input[type=checkbox]").on('change',function(){
    if( $("#foo").prop('checked') == true && $("#foo3").prop('checked') == true) {
        $("#test").show();
    }
  });
});
```

Something you might add is create an else that says if they are not clicked to not show them.